# Extra page numbers appear when I "Update Field" in the List of Tables and List of Figures in my manuscript

Tags: microsoft-word

Extra page numbers appear when I "Update Field" in the List of Tables and List of Figures in my manuscript. I'm using a template the university created. MicroSoft Support played with it for almost 50 minutes before saying they couldn't help me. In the attached screenshot you'll see it didn't do that for Tables 1 and 3, but I can't figure out why.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can't look at the problem without you posting an example document. Also, please indicate which parts of the LoT seems unneeded.

Comment: Any chance you can upload the document somewhere and share the link with us? Also, a screenshot of the field codes would be great: toggle the field codes with ALT + F9 and then please take a screenshot and upload it. 
Does this problem only appear with exisiting image or also when you add a new one?
And the problem persist also when you create a completely new document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Each item that is appearing in your List of Tables is in a paragraph formatted using a style that is incorporated in your List of Tables.

Click in your TOF to go to one of the problem entries. Check the style.

My guess is that you have pressed Enter to split your caption into two lines. If so, instead of Enter, which creates a new paragraph in the same (Caption) style, press Shift+Enter to create a line break within the same paragraph.

When you do this, in the List of Tables, that line break will be replaced with a space so that the two lines will be a single line in the List of Tables.

In Word, a Table of Figures/Tables is simply a specially purposed Table of Contents Field. Here is a link to [my writing on inserting such a table](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#TableFigures). Pretty much anything you see on the Internet about setting up a Table of Contents Field applies to a Table of Tables.

Comment: Thank you, Charles, your suggestion solved the problem perfectly! I appreciate your help very much!!

Comment: @Becky Since it looks like Charles' solution solved your problem, please mark his answer as the solution. This way other helpers can immediately see that they don't need to look into it anymore.

Comment: Will do, Loeli, thanks!